# Unity: Addition of a collider alters GameObject motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a new bullet prefab, and move it from its origin at a constant velocity. This works well enough:

```
void Fire()
    {

        Transform bulletSpawn = transform; // Start bullet at current position

        // Create the Bullet from the Bullet Prefab
        var bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (
            bulletPrefab,
            bulletSpawn.position,
            bulletSpawn.rotation);
        bullet.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (25, 25, 25);
        // Add velocity to the bullet

        bullet.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 1f;
        // bullet.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
        // Destroy the bullet after 5 seconds
        Destroy(bullet, 5.0f);
    }
```

However, I also want it to trigger explosion effects. I uncommented the line that adds a SphereCollider. Another GameObject (with a collider) has this code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(){
        Debug.Log ("collide");
        GameObject expl = Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(expl, 3);
    }
```

As soon as I uncomment the line which adds a SphereCollider, the explosion is triggered (as desired). However, the bullet seems to move randomly (it no longer moves smoothly from the camera). Something about adding the collider messes up the smooth transformation.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I forgot what option it is, but there is an option which provides physics on the colider, turn that off

Comment: you can add the rigidbody and the collider in the inspector. Select the prefab asset and them, no need to do it in code